# java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null" in SQLITE DbController

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

Am trying to update a data in my SQLite database buts it crashing in EditQuickin Class any idea or solution will be welcomed

```
    (QuickinModel)getIntent().getSerializableExtra(Quickin.QUICKIN_EXTRA);

    db = new DbController(this);


    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    FullName = findViewById(R.id.FullNameEdit);
    DgnNumber = findViewById(R.id.DgnEdit);

    Save = findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    spinStatus = findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    FullName.setText(quickinModel.getFullName());
    DgnNumber.setText(quickinModel.getDgnNumber());

    Save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String status = spinStatus.getSelectedItem().toString();

            db.update(Integer.parseInt(quickinModel.getId()), status);

            Toast.makeText(EditQuickin.this, "Updated Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Quickin.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```

This is the Error am seeing

```
Process: codes.dgn.dgn, PID: 26567
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24910757/java-lang-numberformatexception-invalid-int-null)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem is in Integer.parseInt(quickinModel.getId()) check if quickinModel.getId() returns value

Comment: i have check it still could not figure it out, can you explain more

Comment: Its not clear from your code how values are assigned in your quickinModel object. id field in quickinModel is assigned with null. So, in Integer.parseInt(quickinModel.getId()) its passing null as parameter and generating NumberFormatException